# is there any way to show product in form of grid in angular 8 ? such as tabular form with 3 column and nth number of rows

Tags: angular

```
<h4 class ="boxed" align="right">Welcome @{{username}}    </h4>



<div  *ngFor="let product of Allproducts;let index = index" >

<!-- {{(index+1)/2}} -->



<div class="boxed">    

<div class="col-md-2"></div> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

        <img style="border:1px solid green" src="http://localhost:4000/{{product.image}}" width="250px;" height="300px;"/>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

      <b>  {{product.name}}  </b>     
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

     <td><font color="red">MRP ₹<del>{{product.price}}</del></font> <font color="#3EA055"> {{product.discount}}% off </font></td>    
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

      <b>  <td>₹{{product.priceWithDiscount}}</td> </b>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

        <td>
            <button type="button"   class="btn btn-danger" (click)="OnAddCart(product)"><b>Add to cart</b></button>
        </td>
    </div>
</div>

</div>


</div>
```

**
in this above code I am trying to show the product in a grid form such as 3 columns and nth rows. but I am getting it in a single column with nth rows. please help me to solve this problem

pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
**

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7gyw.png)
[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDCCG.png)

Comment: Do not let your cat to tap and lay on ower your keyboard :-)

Comment: Well, you try to show a set of products (not meant in math way)! The html object <table> is highly recomended. When your counter (a variable) overstep the N, clear it, start a new row ( <tr> ) and repeat until the last picture of product. You are welcome!

Comment: can you create stackblitz for this ?

Comment: Sorry, you didnot tell what kind of language you used, if you generate the code on the server side or if you build the page on the client side from JSON data ....

Comment: Array(10)
0: {id: 24, name: "Himalaya Wellness Pure Herbs Ashvagandh (60 tablets)", price: 150, discount: 23, priceWithDiscount: 115, …}
1: {id: 25, name: "Dhootapapeshwar Swamala (1 kg)", price: 1190, discount: 12, priceWithDiscount: 1045, …}
2: {id: 26, name: "Baidyanath Kesari Kalp Royal Chyawanprash (1kg)", price: 690, discount: 30, priceWithDiscount: 482, …}                                                                     Data is coming in this form array of object and I am storing it in an array name as Allproducts